# Perform Some Action after Customer successful Login : Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am creating a module in which I want to  check some condition after customer successfully login, if condition is true then customer login otherwise not.

**I know two ways of doing this :**

1. Overriding `AccountController`
2. With Magento event.

**My query are:**

1. which is the best way?
2. Is there any event with which I can full fill my requirement?

Or if there is other best way of doing this, please recommend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `customer_login`
On the `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` model's method `setCustomerAsLoggedIn()` the event `customer_login` is dispatched.

config.xml

```
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

and your Observer

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

Whenever a user is sucessfully logged in, the event `customer_login` will be fired and you have observed the method `customerLogin()` on that event, so your method from the observer will execute whenever a customer is successfully logged in. 
Here you can check your conditions as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use magento event if possible. But in your case you have to check the condition before customer logins am i right? If so i don't think there is any events for that.So the best way is to override the controller.

Comment: I guess he wants to check some condition after customer successfully login. the questions reads so

Comment: I too think so at first but if you see "if condition is true then customer login otherwise not." Then the condition should be check prior to customer login.

Comment: I want to check after customer successfully login

Comment: then you can use the event `customer_login` as i specified in my answer

Comment: It basically uses Magento's event driven architecture ( Observer Design pattern ), means if the event occurs ( i.e, successful login), then the code you write in your observer get's fired.. Now it's upto you what you want to do there....

Comment: @anz i want to check some condition if condition is true the customer login otherwise not. then how can i do this using this event

Comment: then you should check the condition before the customer logins not after customer logins.I think overriding the controller is the best way.